# Inserting a comment in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to insert a HTML comment inside a innerHTML but it is not accepting in IE8. FF works fine.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>testing</title>
    <script language="javascript">
    function testcmt() {
        var el2 = document.createElement("div");
        el2.innerHTML = "<!--Sample--><p>Sample</p>";
        alert( el2.innerHTML );
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body id="BodyID">
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <input type="button" value="Sample" onmousedown="testcmt(); return false">
</body>
```

IE shows only `<p>Sample</p>` and the comment is missing. Any pointers?

Comment: You wouldn't expect to see the comment being displayed to the screen. Have you checked the dom inspector to see if it's getting added?

Comment: I'm curious what purpose the comment is fulfilling? Because added at runtime, the comment seems useless.

Comment: Also, it may be due to the fact that IE has to parse comments for stuff like `<!--[if lte IE 7]>`

Comment: I am seeing it in the alert and F12 debug mode as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should most likely be using [document.createComment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createComment):

```
function testcmt() {
    var el2 = document.createElement("div");
    el2.setAttribute('id', 'oxe_rem_now' + '232323232323');
    el2.appendChild(document.createComment('text for comment'));
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerText = "Sample";
    el2.appendChild(p);
    alert(el2.innerHTML);
}
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mwFd8/)

Comment: Thanks. I did this in a similar way.

Comment: Actually `innerHTML` doesnt accept comments directly like `el2.innerHTML = "<!--Sample-->";
` . I have to use `createComment` for inserting a comment.